# cannot log in to the mysql server (wamp and wordpress)

Tags: mysql, localhost, phpmyadmin

When I run wamp (an offline webserver) and then run phpmyadmin, user and password are asked. I haven't used wamp in a while so basically I forgot user and password. I've followed some guides like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887507/phpmyadmin-1045-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-after-installing-mysql-comma) but modifying the mentioned file doesn't work.
I suspect the problem is mysql, as said elsewhere but I can't figure out how to set a new password, assuming that's the problem. As far as I understand phpmyadmin user and password must be the same as the mysql ones.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a WordPress specific issue but a WAMP specific issue. The default WAMP MySQL logins are `root` and an leaving the password field blank. Once logged in you can create a new database and set user privileges. The `DB_HOST` depends on your computers hosts file. It could be `localhost` or it could be `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The default Wamp user`s credentials are:

```
username: root
password: (empty, nothing, nada)
```

If you already have a WordPress website previously created on your Wamp system, then go to `/www/yourlocalsite/wp-config.php` and check out the username and password you set. Here`s an example:

```
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Thanks!